# Selenium installed via pip3 but when using import selenium no module named selenium found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

(Mac OS 10.13.6, Python 3.8, Selenium 3.141.0, pip 19.2.3)

**What terminal says**:

```
  pip3 install selenium

Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.8)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**What sublime text says**:

```
import selenium 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christinabenza/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import selenium 
ImportError: No module named selenium
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/test.py"]
[dir: /Users/XXXX/Desktop]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: how about running from python interpreter?

Comment: I am not sure about what could be the problem in Mac OS, but in my Linux environment that used to happen when I installed libraries for python3 but tried execute the code with python2 when both they were installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. This is what happened. Sublime text tried to run python 2.7 instead of 3.8 so I had to tell sublime text to run 3.8. My MAC came with 2.7 already installed